# Identify referenced users in posts via facebook api

Tags: facebook, rest, api, facebook-graph-api

I have an app, that makes requests to get posts from an specific page that i am administrator. But i want to store the facebook users that is referenced in each post published in the page wall. When I get each post I cannot find any field or anyway inside the text of the post to identify the people that is referenced.

Is this possible?

For more info, [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.8/post/) is the reference to the FB documentation to request FB posts.

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean, “referenced” - are you just talking about people/pages _tagged_ in the posts? In that case, you simply search for "tag" on that page ...

Comment: What i was trying to explain, is to identify users referenced in a post. Just like when you post something and you talk about somebody else. An example: "i am going on holidays with my friends @friend1 @friend2" i want to  get profiles of friend1 an friend2

Answer (score 0):

Found it! At the same get request of posts, you must add the field `"message_tags"`

An example:

```
http://fbapi_url/{post-id}?fields=message_tags,message,id,with_tags
```